Repeating a clause in a question
I’m groping for the name of the construction where one directly repeats all or part of a clause in a question as a way of expressing whimsy or making it wistful.

Aren’t we all just people, Jim, aren’t we all?

(I’m also unsure about the punctuation, and FWIW I read it in DeForest Kelley’s voice. )
It might be a repetition cleft, but the examples I can find don’t seem quite apposite, eg.

He wants a good job is what he wants.

from Yale. As always it’s hard to find something when you don’t exactly know how to describe it.
Thank you all for your attention and your contributions.

Are you looking for pseudo cleft?

Not necessarily whimsical: it can be used in a threatening/badgering way: "Did he do that, Jim, did he?" See this question for other examples e.g. "Just the facts, ma'am, just the facts."

The second one is antemetabole. In any event, your questions are about poetic devices. The first is just repetition.

This question is similar to: What is the term for repeating something in an A, B, A fashion? (e.g. "Just the facts, ma'am, just the facts.").  If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Diacope. 'Epizeuxis' can be found in other threads.

See also Is there a name for a structure that intentionally reverses key words for dramatic effect? antimetabole.

@EdwinAshworth   By fiercely closing new questions as duplicates, we are ensuring that no one returns here to post questions about their language problem. And without new questions, older experienced users will disappear, and new users will increasingly  turn to AI; the site will shrink in size and in importance. Soon we'll be looking at fewer than three or four questions posted a day–we're almost there already! Keeping up standards is one thing but throttling new activity is quite another. Can you not wait 48 hours before voting to close a decent question?

@Mari-Lou A CGEL etc were finished as complete works. My understanding of ELU is that it was designed to be primarily a searchable accurate comprehensive reference of the English language, not a self-perpetuating, bloated chat site. Hence the availability of the 'duplicate' CV.

@EdwinAshworth that was fine a couple of years ago when EL&U used to have 30-40 new questions a day. But haven't you noticed the vertiginous drop of visitors ad questions compared to two-three years ago? I suggested waiting 48 hours, it's not as if we're overwhelmed by new content. If the goose isn't laying golden eggs anymore, we should still look after her and give her what she needs to stay alive. Maybe in six months time she'll start laying again.

@EdwinAshworth  In 90 days 930 questions were asked, an average of ten questions a day–these also include old posts, and 611 questions were closed that's almost 66%. Are you interested in the site's survival or more about its legacy?

@Mari-Lou A  My earlier comment indicated that I subscribe to the initially stated mission statement. There are plenty of self-perpetuating EL sites for those wanting to keep repeating the same teachings to questioners.
